# Didn't receive SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN

Tags: windows, service, controls, shutdown, service-control-manager

Is there any scenario that SCM won't deliver `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` to all services or service is not able to receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN`?

I tried to search this on internet but I didn't find any related articles or discussion.

The issue of service didn't receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` is happened mostly on Windows 7 X64 with anti-malware installed while OS shutting down.

Our service have called `SetServiceStatus` with the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN`

Comment: Well, a service won't receive a shutdown message unless it tells the SCM that it accepts them.  And there won't be shutdown messages if the machine crashes rather than shutting down cleanly.  I don't think there are any other legitimate cases.  I think we'd need more information to make any other guesses as to the cause.

Comment: The issue is happened while shutting down. The service which didn't receive shutdown message had told SCM that it accepts shutdown message. It's possible that other services didn't reply the shutdown message and trigger SCM time-out and make our service fail to receive the message?